# How can I include a custom data file with each design automation job?

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

We have a drawing creation task that we'd like to offload to the design automation API.  Every time the task runs, it will need as input a bunch of data that will affect what it creates in the DWG.  What's the best way to make this job-specific data available to each job?  In our case if we could include a text file that might be 1mb in size, that would work fine.

I have looked at the API documentation and other than the zip package, I don't see a way to accomplish this other than attempting to have our automation make outbound web service calls when it runs which i'm not sure would be allowed on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a custom App package with a job that accepts your custom data has input argument, take a look at those demos:

[design.automation-.net-input.output.sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-.net-input.output.sample)

[design.automation-.net-custom.activity.sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-.net-custom.activity.sample)

You can also have your own web service that returns the needed payload, it is possible to issue an http call from an activity, see following sample for a demo:

https://github.com/szilvaa/variadic

Hope that helps